# QT project migrating facing MSB6006 cmd.exe exit with code 2, changing computer env error

Tags: c++, qt

I'm now migrating a Qt project from another computer, both env should be Qt5.9 and Vs2015, windows8.1, msvc.

In fact, I've already passed compiling some project, so the Qt's env should be fine( I've already set Qt-vs addin tools and qt's addtional header).

But some project is showing "MSB6006: cmd.exe exited with code 2", microsoft.cppcommon.targets when I tried to build the project on new computuer using dlls.

I've traced in and vs is showing I have to deal with custombuild.
Checked verbose output of vs and found that something is different with my current qt's path:

There's fully reason to believe that something wrong with my env right now. But I haven't found them all.

path of Qt's file of addtional input and command = cl- is same with the origin computer's, but not my current path, maybe I should check some other env?

Searched for a long time on Internet. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
  1>09:49:50.555   1:2>
    1>Target "CustomBuild: (TargetId:63)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets" from project "D:\MyProject\linnewTwo\SmartCheckInstrument\SmartCheckInstrument.vcxproj" (target "_BuildGenerateSourcesAction" depends on it):
    1>                   Set Property: CustomBuildToolArchitecture=Native32Bit
    1>                   Using "CustomBuild" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll".
    1>                   Task "CustomBuild" (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Task Parameter:
    1>                         Sources=
    1>                             temp\moc\moc_predefs.h.cbt
    1>                                     AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes=
    1>                                     AdditionalInputs=..\..\..\..\QTINSTALL\5.9.3\5.9.3\MSVC2015\mkspecs\features\data\dummy.cpp;
    1>                                     Command=cl -Bx"D:\QtInstall\5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe" -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -E ..\..\..\..\QTINSTALL\5.9.3\5.9.3\MSVC2015\mkspecs\features\data\dummy.cpp 2>NUL >temp\moc\moc_predefs.h
    1>                                     FileType=Document
    1>                                     LinkObjects=true
    1>                                     Message=Generate moc_predefs.h
    1>                                     MinimalRebuildFromTracking=true
    1>                                     Outputs=temp\moc\moc_predefs.h;
    1>                                     TrackerLogDirectory=temp\obj\SmartChe.B419548D.tlog\
    1>                                     TreatOutputAsContent=false (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Task Parameter:BuildSuffix=
    1>                     :VCEnd (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Task Parameter:TrackerLogDirectory=temp\obj\SmartChe.B419548D.tlog\ (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Task Parameter:MinimalRebuildFromTracking=True (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Task Parameter:TrackFileAccess=True (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Task Parameter:ToolArchitecture=Native32Bit (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Write Tracking Logs: (TaskId:34)
    1>                      temp\obj\SmartChe.B419548D.tlog\custombuild.write.1.tlog (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Read Tracking Logs: (TaskId:34)
    1>                      temp\obj\SmartChe.B419548D.tlog\custombuild.read.1.tlog (TaskId:34)
    1>                     No output for D:\MYPROJECT\LINNEWTWO\SMARTCHECKINSTRUMENT\TEMP\MOC\MOC_PREDEFS.H.CBT was found in the tracking log; source compilation required. (TaskId:34)
    1>                     temp\moc\moc_predefs.h.cbt will be compiled as it was not found in the tracking log. (TaskId:34)
    1>                     cl -Bx"D:\QtInstall\5.9.3\5.9.3\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe" -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -E ..\..\..\..\QTINSTALL\5.9.3\5.9.3\MSVC2015\mkspecs\features\data\dummy.cpp 2>NUL >temp\moc\moc_predefs.h (TaskId:34)
    1>                     Generate moc_predefs.h (TaskId:34)
    1>09:49:50.757   1:2>
    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 2.
    1>                   Done executing task "CustomBuild" -- FAILED. (TaskId:34)
    1>09:49:50.758   1:2>
```

new: Just checked the .sln file and found out that Qt5's path is same with previous computer, which means Qt may have written the sln file on it's own, the problem is: How am I supposed to ask Qt and vs to rewrite the sln file, so that I could change the project to a new computer safely?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the reason，there's a file called .user changing the $QDIR value while compiling, edit the value in this file, then change the path of your project in properties, check all addtional path would fix.